# Design Question: how to create a restful interface made out of multiple domain objects?

Tags: rest, grails, grails-orm

So, we're starting with grails in our company and we're creating this application that uses ExtJS as the frontend and Grails in the backend.

Because ExtJS works exclusively with JSON for populating datatables and such, we're presented with the challenge of creating these interfaces that will send and receive JSON objects to ExtJS in a restful manner.

After deliberating on our domain model, we settled on one. Quickly, we realized that some of the tables in the system will be composed of the information from more than one domain object.

After some searching around we found the [JSON RESTful API for GORM](http://grails.org/plugin/json-rest-api) plugin which basically exposes a RESTful interface for any given domain object.

This brings us to the main point of the question.

The way I see it, there are two ways to proceed.

1) Create a controller specific for each data table in ExtJS that will have the different actions and within each action it will create or receive the JSon object to do the CRUD on the different domain objects the data table uses.

This would be more time consuming, in my view. It's an option anyway.

2) The other option is to the the aforementioned plugin by creating a "composite" domain object specific for the datatable we want to populate (each attribute in this object is a column in the datatable). After this, just expose it using the JSON RESTful API for GORM plugin which basically takes care of the whole CRUD actions for us.

Is there even a way to create an object like the one we want in our domain model without actually creating more database tables in the backend?

I believe we're on the right path, we just need a little bit of guidance from experts :)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting.

I ended up using a different approach, let me know what you think.

Basically, we did end up using this plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/json-rest-api to expose a domain class and have all the CRUD operations taken care of.

What we did, was create a custom JSON marshaller for each class, like so.

**Bootstrap.groovy**

```
[...] 
        JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Person){ 
                def returnArray = [:] 

                returnArray['id'] = it.id 
                returnArray['name'] = it.name 
                returnArray['street'] = it.address.street 

                return returnArray 
        }
```

**Person.groovy**

```
      //the plugin exposes the class with this 
       static expose = ['person'] 

       String name 
       Address address 
[...]
```

The marshaller actually acts on how the class will be converted when the "as JSON" method is called.

So now, because of the plugin, we can do

`GET http://mydomain.com/api/person`  and we get a json object that has info from person and other classes like this:

```
{"data":{"id":"1", "name":"Peter", "Spooner St"}}
```

The only thing is that we now have to figure out how to update the street address from an update or a create, if it's possible.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I would recommend creating a set of Command objects and Controllers which handle them. This will elegantly allow for your 'composite' approach.

A [Command object](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.10%20Command%20Objects) is a class which has all the cool validation and data binding capabilities that Domain objects have, but without the direct persistence.

Links to check out:

[Command Objects](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.10%20Command%20Objects)

[JSON Responses](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.1.7%20XML%20and%20JSON%20Responses)

Comment: Interesting... let me read about it. I came up with a different solution in the answers, let me know what you think.